# Linq to entities: update creates new row

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having an issue updating my DB using Linq to entities.

I have 2 entities: Message and Author
My application checks a webservice and pulls messages and authors from the service.

A message and author can already exist in my DB, so I check on duplicates.

This works well for the author. New authors get added, existing ones get updated.

However, the messages give me a weird issue. A message has an obvious relation with author, so I add the author to my message by calling
Message.Author = Author;
where author is the new or updated author from my previous step.

Apparently as soon as I do this, and later in my code call submit changes, entity framework/linq decides to add this new message to the DB, even without me making any call to the mention object. It probably does so because of the author that is linked to it.

Can anyone give me a proper way in pseudo code or something to insert/update both author and message using Linq to entities?

Answer (score 1):

EF always processes all entities in object graph. If you have `Author` attached to EF context and you assign that author instance to detached `Message` instance, EF will detect this as a new entity in object graph. You must tell EF that the entity is not new but existing by changing its state.

```
if (IsNewAuthor(author)) {
   context.Add(author); 
} else {
   context.Attach(author);
   context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(author, EntityState.Modified);
}

message.Author = author;
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(message, EntityState.Unchanged);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: So the EntityState.Unchanged for the message tells the EF that the message has not been changed, hence EF will not see it as a new entity?
And after this code block I check whether my message already exists and do the insert/update for the message itself?

Comment: This code block expects that the message exist in your database and it wasn't changed. If you instead need to add or update it you will use similar block as for author.

Comment: Unfortunately the above solution generates following error on the EntityState.Unchanged line:
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.